# jqGrid expand/collapse event lost when more rows are loaded with virtual scrolling

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

My jqGrid has hierarchical subgrids and i also have virtual scrolling enabled. When I scroll past the first page, new rows are appended to the end of the current page. However, the expand/collapse icons loose their click event and nothing happens when I click on the expand/collapse icon on new rows.

How can I re-bind the click event to the new rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to the issue at jqGrids website, here is the link

http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/subgrids-not-working-with-scroll-1